# Commands and paths to stop and start Apache on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have been looking up different documentation for how to start/stop Apache and from which directory, and have not found the right answer.

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In typical operation (running as a service, not troubleshooting or debugging, etc), the "proper" way to do it is with the `service` command:

```
service apache2 start
service apache2 stop
service apache2 restart
service apache2 reload (when you want to reload the config)
```

The directory that this is run from is inconsequential.  And for your information, the scripts that the service command uses are in `/etc/init.d`; Apache's resides at `/etc/init.d/apache2`.  So `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` etc. will also get what you want; but Ubuntu 10.10 and newer will whine at you to use the `service` command instead.

Comment: I got a "apache: unrecognized service" error when I ran the "service apache2 stop" command. I do have it running because I can go to localhost and get things working there.  Any idea why I got that error?

Comment: @Genadinik Make sure you're using "apache2" instead of just "apache" -- the error message you got would imply that the "2" was missing.  If that still doesn't work, try `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop`?

Comment: It actually worked when I navigated to the scripts directory.  Btw, any idea in which directory I can find the logs for Apache?  Thanks!

Comment: @Genadinik: Logs are in /var/log/apache2 by default.

Comment: this was a life saver I could not for the life of me figure out why service apache restart would not work! just need to add a '2' to it!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
invoke-rc.d apache2 start
```

This should also allow you to run the Apache 2 `init.d` script.